# Wordpress - custom rewrite rule with optional parameter

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have following rewrite rule:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^add/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=2436&type=$matches[1]&parent_id=$matches[2]','top');
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'foo_my_query_vars');
function foo_my_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'type';
    $vars[] = 'parent_id';
    return $vars;
}
```

If I go to `mydomain.com/add/post/12345`, the page is displayed correctly and I get the variables via `get_query_var`.

However, the last part of the url is optional. If I go just to `mydomain.com/add/post/`, I get 404 not found.

How should I change the regex to support the optional last parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple solution is to add another rule:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^add/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=2436&type=$matches[1]&parent_id=$matches[2]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^add/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=2436&type=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using following regex,

```
add\/post\/(\d+)?
```

[Working Demo](http://regexr.com/3aq8d)

Comment: Thanks, but there doesn't have to be the `post` in url. This is the type of item to edit, which means it can be anything else...

Answer (score 0):

Old one but can be useful - please try following pattern:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^add/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)?','index.php?page_id=2436&type=$matches[1]&parent_id=$matches[2]','top');
}
```

In this case `parent_id` will be set to empty string.

I've similar patterns in my WP plugin and they are working as expected.